# como Mostrar Permisos en vue con laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

he traido datos de el modelo usuarios y tengo laravel permission pero al momento de traerlos, no puedo mostrar solamente el nombre del rol en mi componente veu, tengo mi comoponente de la siguiente manera

```
           <tr v-for="user in users"  :key="user.id">
            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            <td>{{user.created_at}}</td>
            <td >{{user.roles}}</td>
           </tr>
```

Mi controlador trae la informacion de la siguiente manera:

```
             $users = User::with('roles')->get();
             return ['users' => $users];
```

y me muestra lo siguiente 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien he probado utilizar lo siguiente pero me desaparece los registros

```
  <td >{{user.roles.name}}</td>
```

Comment: me parece que cuando se trabaja vue sobre plantillas blade de laravel se debe hacer esto `@{{}}` para que la sintáxis de uno no entre en conflicto con otro

Comment: @AlfredoPaz Temo que al momento de agregar @ aparece literal, @[ { "id": 1, "name": "Super_Usuario", "guard_name": .......}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta, solo basta con agregar en tu fuente del for el subvector al cual le estas haciendo referencia para recorrerlo y finalmente decirle que campo de ese subvector vas a mostrar

```
<td v-for="name in user.roles">{{name.name}}</td>
```